# C# OLEDB Database Connection Using Access 2016

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2015, oledb

I have been trying to get a database connection using OLEDB and Access 2016 unfortunately however I am continuously returned the error:

```
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Not a valid file name.
  Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
       at Program_V1._0.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\Tom\Documents\College\Computer_Science_Project _2017_Ver2.0\Program_Files\Program_V1.0\Program_V1.0\Form1.cs:line 24
       at Program_V1._0.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Tom\Documents\College\Computer_Science_Project _2017_Ver2.0\Program_Files\Program_V1.0\Program_V1.0\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

From this section of code:

```
    //Database Connection
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=‪C:\Users\Tom\Documents\College\Computer_Science_Project _2017_Ver2.0\Program_Files\Program_V1.0\Program_V1.0\Databases\DecodeTimes.accdb;
    Persist Security Info=False;";
    connection.Open();
    label3.Text = " - Database Connected - ";
    connection.Close();
```

Try as I might I cannot see any issue with this even after reading about issues regarding compatibility, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looks like you might have an accidental space in the filename.

Comment: @MattWarren Unfortunately, I think the file name is all okay as it was copied straight from file properties, will check though, thanks.

Comment: Shorten the file path and test it locally from a simple file path.. also file names with spaces need to have Quotes wrapped around them 
`Computer_Science_Project _2017_Ver2.0` should be `Computer_Science_Project_2017_Ver2.0`

Comment: @MethodMan After reading your comment I have tried this, I remade a completely new solution and made a form that should simply make the connection when run. I changed all file names and path names to basic character names and ran the whole program locally, but to no avail, the same error seems to be created. Thanks for the help however.

Comment: this should be very simple.. look at the this link http://www.connectionstrings.com then find the section for Access DB
[ACCESS DB CONNECTION STRINGS](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: @MethodMan That is the exact process I went through for finding the Access DB string which is used in my attached code, unfortunately, this seems to be throwing up this issue. I see however Access 2016 is not covered by the correct string for my desired purpose, may this be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you are probably using the incorrect assembly that can read Access 2016 or you have a setting that's off / missing in your connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy your connection string and paste it into Notepad++ set for "ANSI" encoding I see

```
... Data Source=?C:\ ...
```

which tells me that your connection string contains a non-ANSI character. Further investigation shows that the mystery character (which appears as `?` above) is actually the invisible Unicode character U+202A (LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING). Deleting that invisible character from the connection string should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, the problem is now fixed. This may be a dumb question, but how may such a character find its way into this string? Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tom - It often happens as the result of a copy and paste operation.